# Assigned new first name but original name isn't removed

Tags: json, orientdb, gremlin

I am trying to import data from csv. Everything works, but I want to enforce one to many relationship on some data. So if script wants to assign another first name to ID, I want to delete old edge from old first name. Json that is used as parameter for oetl.sh looks like this:

```
{
    "source": { "file": {
       "path": "/root/..../firstName.csv",
       "encoding": "Windows-1250"
       }},
     "extractor": { "csv": {} },
     "transformers": [
       {
           "command": {
                   "language":"Gremlin",
                   "command": "g.V().has('@Class', 'Id').has('ID', ${input.ID}).outE('HasFirstName').remove()"
                   },
           "command":{
                           "command": "create edge HasFirstName from (select  from Id where ID = ${input.ID}) to (select from FirstName where First_name = '${input.first_name}')",
                           "output": "edge"
                   }
       }
     ],
     "loader": {
     "orientdb": {
     "dbURL": "remote:localhost/customer",
     "dbUser": "...",
     "dbPassword": "...",
     "serverUser": "...",
     "serverPassword": "...",
     "dbType": "graph"
    }
  }
}
```

Second command runs, edges are created, but old edge is not removed.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Wlad, could you post the entire json executed ?

Comment: @LucaS json updated

Comment: @LucaS I run oetl script multiple times with different Jsons, I can post other 2 later when I come home.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the pipe.

```
g.V().has('@Class', 'Id').has('ID', ${input.ID}).outE('HasFirstName').remove().iterate()
```

The Gremlin Console automatically iterates the pipe when you use it, but when you have a standalone program, you need to remember to iterate so that your Gremlin query is executed.

Comment: I've tried to add `iterate()` at the end, but nothing changed. I not really sure if gremlin command runs at all.